# How can I use .format() with list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, format, grammar

```
import excel2img
import os 

filelist = [
'1R 1R 1R',
'24 54 994',
'9d 13 885',
]

file_name = "C:/Users/3315/Desktop/fdifndfd.xlsx"
img_name ='C:/Users/3315/Desktop/Weekly/company/{}.png' .format(filelist[1])
excel2img.export_img(file_name, img_name, "", "'{}'!A1:HO29") .format(filelist[1])
```

i want to use list element in format function to use this code as repeatable with **for i in filelist:**. but it keeps fail to use list data although print(filelist[1]) is possible.

I look through many papers but it doesn't deal with list in format function.Can anyone give me the solution?

here's error message
Exception: Failed locating range '{}'!A1:HO29

Comment: What is the error? post the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm guessing because you call `format` on `export_img` and not on the string.

Answer (score 1):

You're formatting the output of your export _img function, not the string you put into it.

That can't work. It's also fundamentally different than what you do in the lines above.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much. I can now go home! -from south korea